# Is there way to install Sense UI in the standard Android emulator?

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, htcsense

I am not sure how to simulate the HTC Sense UI using the emulator.

I know there are 3rd party add-on's available from the SDK Manager, but HTC does not have an entry.  I also see the "Add add-on Site..." button, but can't find the URL for a site at HTC that I could enter here.

I did find a 3rd party "Skin", but I am pretty sure this will just change the "frame" the emulator shows up in (to look like a particular phone).  I want to emulate the UI.  If a skin would work, I would like an official one from HTC if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to do that - HTC has not release a Sense UI APK/suite.  Any solution you may find in the corners of the internet will be shady and potentially untrustworthy.

Comment: I felt kind of stupid asking that question actually, because it seems like such a simple thing (especially for a UI that is so dominant).  I am not surprised about your answer (but was hoping for a different answer).

Comment: It's probably for the best that it does not exist - Android apps should be developed to work with every device possible.

Comment: Yet, my standard spinners, without any specific UI attributes (no color, spacing, etc) don't work on the DroidX.  It would be nice to test my standard app on non-standard UI's.  Which I will have to do on actual devices I guess (so HTC get's their way, and sell's more phones - it's an evil plot).

Comment: Oh, understood.  That's quite a problem.  If nobody has a better answer, feel free to come back and select the check-mark beside my answer to tell others that this is the accepted answer.

Comment: Wanted to reply to this question, since the answer has changed since the original post.  HTC has released their dev toolkit, which allows testing.  It is not part of the standard SDK though (via a plugin, etc).

Answer (score 2):

HTC released their own SDK. They also provided a [installation manual](http://htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/download-instructions).

Did not tried it by my self, yet. I will give it a shot this afternoon and report back.

//edit:
I tried it out and it was disappointing as on those HTC-AVD's there is **no** HTC-Sense installed :( Also you can only choose between a HTC-Phone-AVD (API-Level 10) and a HTC-Tablet-AVD (API-Level 12). So for example the HTC Desire (which I personally own) is not available as avd at all ...

Cheers Ali3n